# Indices manipulation in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, indices

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for j in range(1, len(a)): #assigns as index the number given   
    print(j)    #1 2 3 4 5 Iterates from number given on 1st argument to length of "a"
    key = a[j]
    print(key)  #4 5 6 7 8 got index of j given 1, here starts at second number
    i = j - 1
    print(i)    #0 1 2 3 4 because of j - 1
    a[i+1] = a[i]
    print(i)    #0 1 2 3 4
    print(a[i]) #3 3 3 3 3 WHY?
    i = i - 1
    print(i)   #-1 0 1 2 3 because of i - 1
    a[i+1] = key
    print(key)  #4 5 6 7 8 [-1+1=0] WHY starts from 4?
```

My question really is, why manipulating the `a[i+' ']` messes up with the list? In here it's as `a[i+1]`, but if I write `a[i+3]` it messes with all the numbers, why does that happen? how come they are linked?

Comment: You have no formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address this comment:

```
print(a[i]) #3 3 3 3 3 WHY?
```

You're basically copying the first element into the second, then the third, and so on. To see this, try running this code:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for j in range(1, len(a)):
    i = j - 1
    a[i+1] = a[i]
    print(a)
```

This yields:

```
[3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 8]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

For this comment:

```
print(key)  #4 5 6 7 8 [-1+1=0] WHY starts from 4?
```

Note that in each iteration of the `for` loop, you are temporarily storing `a[j]` into a local variable called `key`. After you modify the list by making various assignments, the `key` variable will still contain `a[j]` by the end of the loop; it hasn't been modified! So it makes sense that printing the `key` later on will give you the same results as when you printed the `key` earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Just future reference, Python isn't C/C++. You don't need to access items via their index in a  `for` loop. If you find yourself needing the index you should use `enumerate()`.

```
for index, value in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print(index, value)
```

will result in:

```
0 'a'
1 'b'
2 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're asking here, so:

```
print(a[i]) #3 3 3 3 3 WHY?
```

In the first iteration, you're setting a[1] = a[0], that is a[1] = 3. In this second iteration, you're setting a[2] = a[1]. a[1] was previously set to 3, so a[2] is set to three. In the third iteration, you set a[3] = a[2], which was previously set to 3... seeing the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:
`a = [3,4,5,6,7,8]` at first, then when the loop starts:

First loop:
`j = 1, key = 4,i = j - 1 = 0`, and you do 
`a[i+1] = a[i]` which now is `a[1] = a[0]`, so you give the value at `a[0] = 3 to a[1]`, so the list is `a = [3,3,5,6,7,8]` now. when you print `a[i]` which is `a[0]` is 3. And you do `i = i -1`, so `i = -1, a[i+1] = a[0] = key = 4`, so the list is `[4,3,5,6,7,8]` now.

Second loop:

```
 j = 2, key = 5,i = j -1 = 1
```

, and you do 
`a[i+1] = a[i]` which now is `a[2] = a[1]`, so you give the value at `a[1] = 3` (because we got the new list from last loop) to `a[2]`, so the list is `a = [4,3,3,6,7,8]` now. when you print `a[i]` which is `a[1]` is `3`. And you do `i = i - 1, so i = 0, a[i+1] = a[1] = key = 5`, so the list is `[4,5,3,6,7,8]` now.

And for the rest of the loop, you can deduce in the same way, then you can get the answer. Hope this is helpful.